# whats my error? java Greeter class file with a driver file. declares the greeter class and implements it in the driver file

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors, syntax-error

On my class file I have

```
public class Greeter {
private String thing;
public Greeter() {
}

public Greeter(String name) {
    this.thing = name;
}

public String Greet() {
    if (thing == null) {
        return "Heeeyyyy buddy!";
    } else {
        return "Hello " + thing;
    }       
}
}
```

On my Driver file I have

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare and construct a Scanner object

    String greeting;
    String name;

    Greeter greeters;
    // Prompt for a name

    System.out.print("What is your name? ");

    // Read the name using the Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = sc.nextLine();

    // Construct a Greeter object
    greeters = new Greeter(name);

    // Get the greeting and save it to a String
    greeting = greeters.Greet();

    // Display the greeting to the command-line System.out.println(greeting);
    System.out.println(greeting);

    // Now do it again using the default constructor System.out.println("Greet someone you can’t remember..."); 
    greeters = new Greeter();
    System.out.println("Greet someone you can’t remember...");
    greeting = greeters.Greet();
    System.out.println(greeting);
} // end of main
} // end of class
```

my error is

Driver.java:14: error: constructor Greeter in class Greeter cannot be applied to given types;

```
    greeters = new Greeter(name);
               ^
```

required: no arguments

found: String

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Driver.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

```
    greeting = greeters.Greet();
                       ^
```

symbol:   method Greet()
  location: variable greeters of type Greeter

Driver.java:22: error: cannot find symbol

```
    greeting = greeters.Greet();
                       ^
```

symbol:   method Greet()

location: variable greeters of type Greeter
3 errors

I've no clue what is wrong and I double checked my code and I thought it should run properly? Appreciate the help

Comment: My guess is that it's not picking up the same Greeter code that you've shown here... (Note that Java naming conventions would suggest that the `Greet` method should be called `greet`. I'd also recommend declaring local variables at the point of first use, rather than declaring them all at the top.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try your code in Eclipse and it work fine. I think you can try clean and run it again. Or u can try it in another IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had run it on idea,however,it worked well,i guess you write it by txt or notepad,maybe you should run it on eclipse or other IDE,it doesn't have any error.